# Correctly configure Git with Jenkins under Windows 7

Tags: git, windows-7, jenkins

I am using Jenkins 1.484 under Windows 7 and I have troubles with cloning a git repository.

I have configured Git correctly, but when I try to clone a repository, this takes forever and never succeed. It gets halted just after:

git --version
git version 1.7.9.msysgit.0

If after ten minutes I do halt the build, that's what I see:

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone git@github.com:GBSA/Gottware-server.git
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone git@github.com:GBSA/Gottware-server.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.clone(GitAPI.java:271)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1040)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:982)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:851)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:824)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:982)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1138)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1256)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:589)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:494)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1502)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe clone --progress -o origin git@github.com:GBSA/Gottware-server.git G:\jenkins\workspaces\gottwareproductiontests
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:870)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.access$000(GitAPI.java:40)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI$1.invoke(GitAPI.java:267)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI$1.invoke(GitAPI.java:246)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:851)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:824)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.clone(GitAPI.java:246)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(Native Method)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.join(Proc.java:319)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:352)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:851)
    ... 20 more
Trying next repository
ERROR: Could not clone repository
FATAL: Could not clone
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1052)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:982)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:851)
```

If on the contrary I try to execute the same GIT I have configured from the command line, the clone succeed

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" clone --progress -o origin git@github.com:GBSA/Gottware-server.git G:\jenkins\
workspaces\gottwareproductiontests
Cloning into 'G:\jenkins\workspaces\gottwareproductiontests'...
remote: Counting objects: 38007, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (16268/16268), done.
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, the Jenkins process is run as a system service so it is running as the SYSTEM user and not using your account. You are using a git@github.com type URL so that is trying to use SSH which will require a ssh key to be found either from an ssh agent like pageant or from ~/.ssh/identity when run as the SYSTEM user.

The simplest solution will be to use a http or https transport instead. As you are pulling and not pushing when you perform builds, you don't need to configure a username or password for these protocols. You could possibly use the git protocol (git://github.com/...) if you local network configuration will permit that.

Alternatively, you can use psexec from sysinternals to get a command prompt as the system user and fix up the local environment so that ssh will work. `psexec -i -s cmd.exe` will yield a SYSTEM command prompt and you can then run the msysGit bash shell and set up a suitable ssh key to register with the remote system. I've been using this on XP - so its possible it is no longer applicable on Win7. You can also configure Jenkins to run as another user account but I've not used that method locally.

Comment: My repository is private, why using http/https will solve that?

Comment: Well now you have added that piece of information we can presumably exclude the use of https. Unless github private repositories allow you to use authenticated https. However, the fault is most likely still that you are operating the build as a user that does not have credentials to access the remote. You have to fix that somehow and I offer up a couple of possible solutions.